# Fully transparent proxy

Tags: linux, man-in-the-middle, proxy, router, iptables

By default, mitmproxy will use its own local IP address for its server-side connections. What I want instead is mitmproxy to use the client’s IP address for server-side connections.

The following config is supplied to make this work:

```
CLIENT_NET=192.168.1.0/24
TABLE_ID=100
MARK=1

echo "$TABLE_ID     mitmproxy" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d $CLIENT_NET -j MARK --set-mark $MARK
iptables -t nat \
    -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s $CLIENT_NET \
    --match multiport --dports 80,443 -j \
    REDIRECT --to-port 8080

ip rule add fwmark $MARK lookup $TABLE_ID
ip route add local $CLIENT_NET dev lo table $TABLE_ID
```

Mitmproxy is listening on the router (`192.168.178.40`) on port: `8080`

However, my setup consists of a custom Debian router with 2 NICs.

- One internet-facing `wlp2s0` (also used to SSH into it) with address: `192.168.178.40`
- One NIC set as default gateway `enp4s0` for the target client at: `10.0.0.1`

The client connects to the default gateway with the address `10.0.0.12`

By default I use the following IP table rules to redirect my client traffic to port 8080:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8008
```

While this works as intended, I'd like to be able to spoof the client source address so that the HTTP(S) requests captured match the TCP packets and other traffic also coming from the client.

Here's a picture to visualize my setup because I am pretty horrible at explaining:

[image: Transparent proxy setup.]

Comment: Since request comes from mitmproxy host - it will have this host IP, with an exception to have some information regarding original in the headers.

Comment: @bluszcz The idea is that mitmproxy can spoof the source address using --spoof-source-address. However, needed first is the above config, but I don't know how to adjust this to my 2 NIC setup. read more here: https://mitmproxy.org/docs/latest/howto-transparent/

Comment: Right, did you follow all the docs from https://mitmproxy.org/docs/latest/howto-transparent/#linux-fully-transparent-mode ? Using root accounts and others?

```./mitmproxy_shim $(which mitmproxy) -T --spoof-source-address```

Comment: @bluszcz I see now what the `mitmproxy_shim` is for. However, I am still not sure if there needs to be anything changed in the iptables config in order for me to spoof the correct client source (`10.0.0.x` instead of `192.168.178.x`)

Comment: What isn't clear to me is if this is actually an internet-facing router; i.e. is it performing NAT/why do you need to spoof the client's address? If there is NAT, the client's IP address as seen by websites will be the same as the router's IP address anyway.

Comment: It seems that mitmproxy used to support this, but it was removed in v7!  https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/#full-transparent-mode-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

> By default mitmproxy will use its own local IP address for its server-side connections. What I want instead is mitmproxy to use the client’s IP address for server-side connections.

On most setup (Attacked host / Attacker host on the same LAN, both behind an internet router, destination site on Internet), your problem is not one, basically because internet host will **always** see your internet router public address.

The only setup where it's a problem is if the destination site is on the same LAN.
In this case, as already said by @antonio-zunic, the only way to achieve this is by doing ARP-spoofing.

Answer (score -5):

You cannot use Client's ip...proxy is intermediary device/software to whom client ask for data. Client asks for proxy to contact server, proxy contacts server. If you want to bypass client configuration for proxy you have to apply arpspoof command (arpspoof -i  -t  -r  , using these you don't have to route your traffic to proxy via router.

Comment: *to whom client ask* - well, no, **transparent** proxy is the one where client does not negotiate with the proxy.

Comment: Transparent proxy means that client is Unaware of Proxy. It doesnt have to mean that the traffic is not going through proxy.

Comment: Yes, of course, how else could it work. But client does not know about the proxy, which your answer says.

Comment: Ok, gotta explore that...learning on mistakes. :D